# How can I know if something is a Integration Test or Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I'm adding tests to this function that is going to reach out my auth system and verify if the user has access to a specific resource. I'm confuse if this test is a unit test or integration test. I would say that is an unit test, but it's doing IO and using external services, so it might be a integration test.

Thank you.

Comment: you are asking us if it's an integration test or an integration test. The answer, unsurprisingly is that it's an integration test ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you made a mistake in your question and you meant to ask if it's a unit test or an integration test.

Anything that reaches out to an external system, be it a file on disk, database, API, auth system is an integration test.

Unit tests are self contained, don't touch any external systems and typically only focus on very small pieces of code.

The reason for this is that unit tests are meant to be very quick, don't require setup, don't require any settings that might change, they're all about functionality.

If you were to mock the auth system dependency then that would make it a unit test. However, if your purpose is to verify that the auth system works correctly then definitely go with integration tests.

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake when writing the question, thanks for pointing that out. By the way, I was in the middle of the daily standup when I read your comment, and I was not able to contain the laugh, kudos for u haha.